# How to attach javadoc for jar in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any way to attach javadoc for `struts.jar` in Eclipse, like we attach it for core Java which is a zip file distributed under JDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to download the source files for any jar file which we are using. 
After that we can attach that zip or jar file to eclipse by using to double click the used java class name and then click on link attach java source and then select respective jar and zip of source file.
    It may be that sometimes after attaching the java source zip or jar source file is not opening in that case, you can create jar by using the jar command from command prompt by taking the package which you want to include.And after creating this jar we can attach it through the previous step. The source file would definitely be open.

Answer (score 3):

For to add the Document to the Library, do the following things.

Project(Right Click)->Properties->Build Path -> libraries ->JRE System Library then expand each api and Added the location of API.

Now select the Library for which you want to add the Documents.

Click on Edit, then Navigate browser to select the Directory of the Documentation directory. Please try with only Directory, not the index.html file.

Comment: i have added javadoc for j2se but now i wamt to add javadoc for struts.jar,servlet-api.jar,jboss-javaee.jar etc. So from where i will get the jar, folder or zip whatever needed to attach with eclipse. I have also applied to add javadoc by using URL [link](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/) but don't get any good result yet.

Comment: Do you want to add doc or want jar file for the desire api ??

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on the jar, click "Properties", then fill the javadoc location.

Comment: can you please tell me that from where i can get javadoc(in Zip format) for struts and java-j2ee.jar?

Comment: http://struts.apache.org for struts. I don't know what the other jar is exactly, but the full JEE documentation is at http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/ (and you can use a URL in Eclipse. No need for a zip or jar file).